# Conditionally read strings.xml values in another xml file like manifest.xml

Tags: android

simple question.
I got this strings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_id_prod">XXXXXXX</string>
    <string name="app_id_test">YYYYYYY</string>
    <string name="test_mode">YYYYYYY</string>
</resources>
```

And the manifest file needs to read "app_id_prod" or "app_id_test" based on "test_mode" value lets say TRUE or false.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

EDIT: Something like

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >       
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        if(!test_mode)
        <android:value="@string/app_id_prod" />
        else
         <android:value="@string/app_id_test" />
    <meta-data>
   ...
 </application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Gradle Android plugin resource merging and [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) for variation like this.

For example, let's say you have the build flavors `test` and `prod`. Then put a resource file containing your `@string/app_id` under both `src/{test,prod}/res/values` (assuming default source paths), and just refer to the string as `@string/app_id` in manifest.

(It's possible you don't need flavors and can do similar variation with the `debug` and `release` variants.)